# How do I generate an amazon S3 file url?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have created the file in an amazon S3 bucket. I know that the url format is:

```
http://ptedotnet.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/UserContent/Uploads/54/26.jpg
```

However I want to be able to work out what the 's3-eu-west-1' bit is without having to explicitly know this in my application. I have seen that in the API there is a call which I can make to get the location...

```
GetBucketLocationRequest bucketRequest = new GetBucketLocationRequest();
            bucketRequest.BucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_Bucket"].ToString();
            GetBucketLocationResponse ree = client.GetBucketLocation(bucketRequest);
            string location = ree.Location;
```

But this only returns 'eu' so im wondering how to get the other parts. The less the user has to configure on the application the better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use *{bucket}*.s3.amazonaws.com.

i.e. http://ptedotnet.s3.amazonaws.com/UserContent/Uploads/54/26.jpg

Comment: So I can! Thanks :-) do you know if this is a supported format?

Comment: According to their doco it is. (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectGET.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [S3SignURL](https://github.com/DigitalBodyGuard/S3SignURL) to make a signed URL